# How do let a code running in a pod knows its pod name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I have some go program running inside a pod. How would I write code to let it know its pod name with go-client library ?

Comment: Have you tried os.Hostname()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pod information can be exposed via [Env Vars or Downward Api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/).

> The spec and metadata from pod gives you all the info.

Sample pod def from official k8s docs.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_NODE_NAME MY_POD_NAME MY_POD_NAMESPACE;
          printenv MY_POD_IP MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT;
          sleep 10;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice and clean solution.